# capturing a desktop , other then the active one

Tags: winapi, screenshot, gdi

(c/win32)

I was using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx to capture the current desktop. 
They uses:
    GetDC(NULL);

to get the running desktop. 
Let's say I have few desktops (for example, using sysinternal's `desktop` tool). 
I thought I could use `OpenDesktop` and then use the handle in `GetDC` but it just gives me a black pic. 
is there other way of capturing other desktops in the current station (within the current session of course)?

Answer (score 2):

`OpenDesktop()` returns an `HDESK` but `GetDC()` requires an `HWND` instead.

Try calling `SetThreadDesktop()` first, so that your thread is associated with the target desktop, then try `GetDC(NULL)` again.

Comment: I've tried it. using the `sysinternals` tool `desktops.exe` I had a valid desktop named `Sysinternal Desktop 2". it was opened properly with `OpenDesktop()` , `SetThreadDesktop()` returns `TRUE`, and `GetDC()` returns a valid `HDC` . yet, I'm getting a black bitmap (with the same code that works fine for the same scenario , without changing the thread's desktop)